# julia error when using Pkg.add

Tags: github, julia

I just install julia in ubuntu and found some problems when I added a package.

```
julia> Pkg.Add("Gadfly")
ERROR: UndefVarError: Add not defined
```

I also tried to update julia but an error popped up:

```
julia> Pkg.update()
INFO: Initializing package repository /home/jing/.julia/v0.5
INFO: Cloning METADATA from git://github.com/JuliaLang/METADATA.jl
fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
github.com[0: 192.30.252.131]: errno=Connection timed out

ERROR: failed process: Process(git clone -q -b metadata-v2 git://github.com/JuliaLang/METADATA.jl METADATA, ProcessExited(128)) [128]
in run at ./process.jl:531
in anonymous at pkg/dir.jl:52
in cd at ./file.jl:22
in init at pkg/dir.jl:50
in cd at pkg/dir.jl:28
in update at ./pkg.jl:45
```

Could anyone please help me fix this problem? 
Thanks!!

Comment: I just noticed that I should use Pkg.add(...) with lower case of "add", but I still got the same error as what Pkg.update(...) responded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key message here is

```
fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
github.com[0: 192.30.252.131]: errno=Connection timed out
```

It seems you didn't have an internet connection when this was run. Make sure you have internet and that you can access github on the machine this is running on.

Comment: You are right. I referred the doc  http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/manual/packages/?highlight=insteadof#adding-and-removing-packages and fixed it successfully by entering command git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git:// in terminal.