# Pkg.add("IJulia") yields "ERROR: failed process Process(`git clone ... "

Tags: git, github, julia, ijulia-notebook

Trying to add IJulia to the Julia package so it can be run in Jupyter notebook. The command

```
Pkg.add("IJulia")
```

gives this string of info and errors:

```
INFO: Initializing package repository /var/root/.julia/v0.4
INFO: Cloning METADATA from git://github.com/JuliaLang/METADATA.jl
fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
github.com[0: 192.30.252.128]: errno=Operation timed out

ERROR: failed process: Process(`git clone -q -b metadata-v2 git://github.com/JuliaLang/METADATA.jl METADATA`, ProcessExited(128)) [128]
 in run at /Applications/Julia-0.4.1.app/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib
 in anonymous at pkg/dir.jl:52
 in cd at /Applications/Julia-0.4.1.app/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/sys.dylib
 in init at pkg/dir.jl:50
 in cd at pkg/dir.jl:28
 in add at pkg.jl:23
```

The obvious answer would be that I don't have a connection to github, but that is not the case; I can clone from github from the command line (e.g.

```
git clone https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh.git
```

worked fine)

This is with Julia-0.4.1, git version 2.4.9 (Apple Git-60), MacOSX 10.10.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to enter the command

```
git config --global url."https://".insteadOf git://
```

in the command line.  This is mentioned in the comments of the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33378792/julia-error-when-using-pkg-add), but it seems helpful to put in a standalone answer.

Comment: For some reason it hasn't worked for me on git 2.9.3 . Adding quotes around `git://` helped.